# Cannot find way to iterate two ways in for loop while using operations on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

So I'm trying to calculate the manhattan distance between a `query` and a dataframe called `data`.

The code below is what I have so far, and in terms of the calculations, it does the right thing. The problem is that I have tried and tried to find a way to get it to iterate also through the column names to avoid all of this repetition of code through columns such as `LIFE_EXP` etc.

How can I optimize this for loop?

My other query is about getting it into a form where I can have pairs of values i.e country name and output, so that I can sort by the output values?

Help please, I am very new to python!

```
list = []

for row  in range(len(data)):
    list.append((data['COUNTRY_ID'][row], abs(query['LIFE_EXP'].sub(data['LIFE_EXP'][row])) + abs(query['TOP10_INCOME'].sub(data['TOP10_INCOME'][row])) + abs(query['INFANT_MORT'].sub(data['INFANT_MORT'][row])) +abs(query['MIL_SPEND'].sub(data['MIL_SPEND'][row])) +abs(query['SCHOOL_YEARS'].sub(data['SCHOOL_YEARS'][row]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since pandas supports the plus operator, you can use the sum function:

```
list = []
column_list = ['LIFE_EXP', 'TOP10_INCOME', 'INFANT_MORT', 'MIL_SPEND', 'SCHOOL_YEARS']

for row  in range(len(data)):
    list.append((data['COUNTRY_ID'][row], sum([abs(query[col].sub(data[col][row])) for col in column_list])))
```